# HttpServletRequest.getLocale() returns null even after setting "Accept-Language" header

Tags: http, servlets, http-headers, locale, http-accept-language

I am setting the value of `Accept-Language` : en-gb, in my REST `Http` call,  but when I am trying to fetch the locale in my code, it is showing null.

```
Accept-Language : en-gb
Accept-Language: da, en-gb;q=0.8, en;q=0.7
```

In the code

`httpServletRequest.getLocale()` is always coming as `null`.

What could be the possible reason ?

Comment: What container are you using? According to the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getLocale()), it should be returning the default.

Comment: I am using rest webservices, jax-rs, on Jboss server.